# Form submission refreshes page even with return false and preventdefault

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

```
setUser = () => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { setUser } = this.props;
    const userEmail = this.refs.userEmail.value;
    setUser(userEmail);
    this.refs.userEmail.value = "";
    return false;
}
```

Why/how does the form still submit? I am using React, Redux and Electron when I am experiencing this problem. Thank you for any advice.

```
render() {
    const {options} = this.props;

    return (
        <div>
          <div className="optionsModalContent">
            <div className={style.optionsModalTitleBar}>
              <div className={style.optionsModalTitle}>Options</div>
              <div className={style.optionsModalExit} onClick={this.exitModal}>X</div>
            </div>
            <div className={style.optionsModalContentInner}>
              <div className={style.optionsModalOptionsList}>
                <div className={style.optionItem}>
                  <form onSubmit={this.setUser}>
                    <input type="text" id="userEmail" ref="userEmail" placeholder="Set account email"/>
                  </form>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: can you provide more detailed code?

Comment: That's really the only part that seems relevant, but I've updated to include the render() statement as well. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't passing "event" to my form handler function, so event.preventDefault() did nothing... Sigh.. lol

Comment: Much thanks to you for making me look beyond the area I initially judged to be the problem.